# Word for an ultimate target that MUST be achieved

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, vocabulary, emphasis

Looking for any ideas as to a word or phrase that  can be used for subject title.

Say we have a deadline at the end of the year with a target/objective that must be achieved at all costs.

Is there anything that really emphasises the fact that this target must be achieved?

Comment: In the United States, where _deadline_ has become so commonplace that it expresses less urgency than it might have done some years ago, I have heard some people in business use the phrase "drop dead date"—which reanimates the old sense of the more familiar term to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

If it's merely a *target* ([ODO definition 1.2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/target)) or *objective* ([ODO noun definition 1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/objective)), there's no 'emphasis' that the target must be achieved - it may simply be aspirational. If you want to emphasise that the target must be achieved, consider calling it an *obligation*.

> **obligation** *noun*
>   1 An act or course of action to which a person is morally or legally bound; a duty or commitment.
>   ‘We must do our utmost to honor the obligations contained in these commitments.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obligation)

Comment: Also requirement or [gating criteria](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94972/whats-the-correct-term-for-gating-criteria).

Comment: @Davo those are good answers. I'd upvote *requirement* if you submit it as an answer.

Comment: @Davo I just saw your posted answer - upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **obligaion**, offered in a previous answer, other suitable options include, from OLD:

> **[requirement](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/requirement)**
>
> 1.1 A thing that is compulsory; a necessary condition.
>   *‘applicants must satisfy the normal entry requirements’*

And the term I've heard used quite a bit: **[gating criteria](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94972/whats-the-correct-term-for-gating-criteria)**, which is used in project management to mean a condition required to pass on to the next phase. [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gating+criteria&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgating%20criteria%3B%2Cc0) show this phrase to be a recent addition to the language.

Answer (score 1):

In my work we called this a *drop-dead date,* which I am surprised to see does actually feature in OED:

> **drop-dead** *adj.*
>
> 2. Chiefly *Business.* Designating the latest date or time by which a task must be completed or a result achieved.
>
> > 1966   *Missiles & Rockets* 4 Apr. 16   February was the ‘drop-dead’ point for developing a '69 Mars probe and any late starting date would be inordinately costly.
> > 1983   *Daily Tel.* 1 Nov. 1/8   The 300-day rule is known as the ‘drop-dead’ date in the shipyard contracts, being the moment an order can be abandoned without legal claim.
> > 1998   *N.Y. Times* 3 Mar. a15/3   Republicans who support setting a drop-dead date for the current system believe that is the best way to force a decision on an issue that will put members of Congress in the line of fire from nearly every special interest group.

It's perhaps a little informal, but the question doesn't mention any particular requirement for the level of formality.

Answer (score 0):

"Requisite" pops to mind, but I don't feel that it conveys the sense of urgency that you want. "Vital", maybe?